# variables are not created even though I declared them Correctly

Tags: java, arraylist, runtime-error

*I am trying to Creating a library management system which is capable of issuing books to the students.

Book should have info like:

1. Book name

2. Book Author

3. Issued to

4. Issued on

User should be able to add books, return issued books, issue books*

*When I am executing the below code and choosing option 1 as choice I am not able to give input to the bName String and author String*

*am I doing something wrong, I am new to java please help me*

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

/*
Creating a library management system which is capable of issuing books to the students.
Book should have info like:
1. Book name
2. Book Author
3. Issued to
4. Issued on
User should be able to add books, return issued books, issue books
 */
class BookInfo
{
    protected String name,author,issuedTo,issuedOn;
    public BookInfo(String bName,String bAuthor) {
        this.addBook(bName,bAuthor);
    }
    public String getBookName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public String getAuthor()
    {
        return author;
    }
    public String getIssuedOn()
    {
        return issuedOn;
    }
    public String getIssuedTo()
    {
        return issuedTo;
    }
    public void addBook(String name,String author)
    {
       this.name=name;
       this.author=author;
    }
    public void issueBook(String name)
    {
        this.issuedTo=name;
        LocalDateTime t=LocalDateTime.now();
        DateTimeFormatter dTF=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MMM/yyyy       HH:mm:ss");
        this.issuedOn=t.format(dTF);
    }
  public void returnIssuedBooks()
  {
      issuedTo=null;
      issuedOn=null;
  }

}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        ArrayList<BookInfo> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
        int choice;
        String bName;
        String name;
        String author;
        boolean isTrue = true;
        Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("welcome to the Library Management System");
            while (isTrue) {
                System.out.println("choose from the options below :");
                System.out.println("press 1 for adding the book");
                System.out.println("press 2 for issuing the book");
                System.out.println("press 3 for returning the issued book");
                System.out.println("press 4 to exit");
                choice = obj.nextInt();
                try {
                    switch (choice) {
                        case 1:
                            System.out.println("enter the name of the book :");
                            bName = obj.nextLine();
                            System.out.println("enter the author of the book");
                            author = obj.nextLine();
                            l1.add(new BookInfo(bName,author));
                            break;

                        case 2:
                            System.out.println("enter the name of the book to issue");
                            bName = obj.nextLine();
                            System.out.println("enter your name :");
                            name = obj.nextLine();
                            for (BookInfo obj2 : l1) {
                                if (obj2.getBookName().equals(bName)) {
                                    obj2.issueBook(name);
                                }
                            }
                            break;

                        case 3:
                            System.out.println("enter the name of the book you want to return");
                            bName = obj.nextLine();
                            for (BookInfo obj2 : l1) {
                                if (obj2.getBookName().equals(bName)) {
                                    obj2.returnIssuedBooks();
                                }
                            }
                            break;

                        case 4:
                            isTrue = false;
                            break;

                        default:
                            throw new Exception();
                    }
                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("enter the correct input");
                }
            }
    }
    }
```

this is the following output

```
welcome to the Library Management System
    choose from the options below :
    press 1 for adding the book
    press 2 for issuing the book
    press 3 for returning the issued book
    press 4 to exit
    1
    enter the name of the book :
    enter the author of the book
```

Comment: also, don't call non-final methods from your constructor, you'll never know what that gives you when you extend the class

Comment: thank you for your suggestion Stultuske☺☺

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of the **Scanner.nextInt** method does not read the newline character in your input created by hitting **"Enter"** and so the call to **Scanner.nextLine** returns after reading that newline.
There are two options to resolve this issue,

**1. Read the input through Scanner.nextLine and convert your input to the proper format you need**

```
    Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice = Integer.parseInt(obj .nextLine());
```

**2. Add Scanner.nextLine call after each Scanner.nextInt**

```
    Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice = = obj.nextInt();
    obj.nextLine();
```